# Why if position is not working in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with checking if my gameobject is on a position, let me explain: I'm making a game with a kind of "Slider", like the Unity UI Slider, (But not using the slider, it's just to compare), this Slider was made with GameObjects. The cursor was designed to move automatically and you press the screen when the cursor is in a specific zone. This is the cursor code:

```
 private System.Random FirstRnd = new System.Random();
     private int FirstCounter;
     private float Speed = 50f;
     private float AntiSpeed = -50f;
     private int SecondCounter;
     private System.Random SecondRnd = new System.Random();
     private Vector3 StartLVector = new Vector3(-2.05f, -0.55f, 10f);
     private Vector3 StartRVector = new Vector2(2.05f, -0.55f);
     private Vector3 CenterL = new Vector3(-0.02f, 0.55f, 10f);
     private Vector3 CenterR = new Vector3(1.14f, -0.55f, 10f);
     private GameObject Cursor;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start ()
     {
         Cursor = GameObject.Find("Cursor");
     }
     private void FixedUpdate()
     {
         SecondStarting();
     }
     void Starting()
     {
         FirstCounter = FirstRnd.Next(1, 3);
         if (FirstCounter == 1)
         {
             transform.position = StartLVector;
         }
         else if (FirstCounter == 2)
         {
             transform.position = StartRVector;
         }
     }
     void SecondStarting()
     {
         Debug.Log("Puga");
         if (Cursor.transform.position == StartLVector)
         {
             Cursor.transform.Translate(Speed, 0, 0);
         }
         else if (Cursor.transform.position == StartRVector)
         {
             Cursor.transform.Translate(AntiSpeed, 0, 0);
         }
         else if (Cursor.transform.position == CenterL)
         {
             SecondCounter = SecondRnd.Next(1, 3);
             if (SecondCounter == 1)
             {
                 Cursor.transform.Translate(Speed, 0, 0);
             }
             else if (SecondCounter == 2)
             {
                 Cursor.transform.Translate(AntiSpeed, 0, 0);
             }
         }
         else if (Cursor.transform.position == CenterR)
         {
             SecondCounter = SecondRnd.Next(1, 3);
             if (SecondCounter == 1)
             {
                 Cursor.transform.Translate(Speed, 0, 0);
             }
             else if (SecondCounter == 2)
             {
                 Cursor.transform.Translate(AntiSpeed, 0, 0);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

As far I can see, I don't detect a problem here. Do you see something?
I want to add something, the message "Puga" yes prints, but, below it, nothing seems to compile

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Try printing out the `Cursor.transform.position` instead of `puga` and see why it doesn't match your vectors. I have a feeling it is because you are using local space coordinates for the `Center`/`Start` vectors, but `transform.position` returns world space...

Comment: I don't know if it's related but your `StartRVector` is a `Vector3` and you are setting it equal to a `Vector2` which would mean your Z position for `StartRVector` does not match `StartLVector`.

Comment: @AlexMyers I have changed the Vector3 to Vector2, Thanks but, it still not working...

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks for your idea, curiously, in the  inspector it shows me that the cursor position is 2.05, but with printing the value, it displays (-2.1, -0.6, 18.8)...

Comment: Check the result by use `transform.localPosition` instead if `transform.position`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparisons by floats are inherently inaccurate and will often return false even when they appear equal. A vector 3 consists of three floats (xyz).
Even though unity's == operator for vector3 compares the square magnitude, You still have a pretty large margin for error.

An Alternative could be that you try and round the xyz properties (or xy for vector2) to one or two decimals and the compare them.

```
System.Math.Round(value, 2);
```